# Slicing a string with a list as input

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

```
my_list = [6, 9, 12]
```

I have a string:

```
my_string = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
```

I want to slice the string as such:

```
my_string[:6]
my_string[6:9]
my_string[9:12]
my_string[12:]
```

Notice that the slice range are the elements of my_list.

Output:

```
The qu
ick
 br
own fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

Or into a list. But, I am struggling with an algorithm that does the slicing.

Comment: how do you want it? `[:0th] [1st:2nd]` like that for whole list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution

```
L=[0]+my_list+[len(my_string)]
for a in range(len(L)-1):
    print(my_string[L[a]:L[a+1]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `zip` and slicing. Modify your `my_list` by adding a 0 at the beginning prior to applying `zip` and slice:

```
my_list = [6, 9, 12]
my_string = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."

my_list = [0] + my_list
for x, y in zip(my_list, my_list[1:]):
    print(my_string[x: y])

print(my_string[my_list[-1]:])

# The qu
# ick                                                          
# br                                                         
# own fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

Or rather if you need `my_list` to be unchanged for some reason, use a separate variable here: `my_list1 = [0] + my_list` and `for x, y in zip(my_list1, my_list1[1:]):`.

Comment: `The qu
own fox jumps over the lazy dog.
ick
own fox jumps over the lazy dog.
 br
own fox jumps over the lazy dog.` It produces like this looks like OP want different

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari, are you sure?

Comment: Yup I checked the output

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari, please make sure that last line is not indented.

Comment: Works well! awsome

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list = [6, 9, 12]
my_string = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
start = 0
for end in my_list:
    print(my_string[start:end])
    start = end
print(my_string[end:])
```

Worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

This worked according to output required

```
my_list = [6, 9, 12]

my_string = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."

resultstring = ''

temp = 0

for i in range(0,len(my_list)):
    resultstring+=my_string[temp:my_list[i]]
    resultstring+='\n'
    temp = my_list[i]

resultstring+=my_string[temp:]

print resultstring
```

Output:

```
The qu
ick
 br
own fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function which returns a generator, to be used wherever you need to present the result.

```
def slice_string_by(my_string, my_list):
  memo = 0
  for idx in my_list:
    size = idx - memo
    chunck = my_string[0:size]
    yield chunck
    my_string = my_string[size:]
    memo = idx
  yield my_string
```

---

Then you can just call:

```
res = slice_string_by(my_string, my_list)
```

The result is a generator, converting to a list you get:

```
list(res) #=> ['The qu', 'ick', ' br', 'own fox jumps over the lazy dog.']
```

---

Or you can just iterate over it to print the elements:

```
for chunk in slice_string_by(my_string, my_list):
  print(chunk)

# The qu
# ick
#  br
# own fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```